# Did Andrew report Fletcher for being an abusive teacher?

Tags: whiplash

After watching the film *Whiplash* I wasn't sure if Andrew actually reported Fletcher to the woman who was sorting things out with Andrew's father.

This event led Fletcher to sabotage Andrew's career - but only because he accused Andrew of telling on him. Was he correct?

Comment: Isn't this *in* the movie, though? He's reluctant at first to speak against Fletcher, then relents and says "tell me what to say"?

Answer (score 6):

## Yes

Andrew testifies against Fletcher, he is asked to following the suicide of Sean Casey.

> ***RACHEL:*** Would you characterize
>   his conduct as extreme, Andrew?
>   Did he ever intentionally inflict
>   emotional distress?
>
> []
>
> This would not be a public hearing,
>   you know.
>   Fletcher would never know
>   it was you who spoke up.
>
> **ANDREW:** Why would you do this to me?
>
> **JIM:** Do you think that I would let him
>   put my son through hell
>   and then just walk away
>   scot-free?
>   Don't you know
>   I would never let that happen?
>   That there is nothing in the world
>   more important to me than you?
>   Don't you know that?
>
> **RACHEL:**
>   Andrew?
>
> []
>
> **RACHEL:**
>   Andrew?
>
> **ANDREW:** Just tell me what to say.

This leads to Fletcher getting fired, which is confirmed when Andrew meets Fletcher in the Jazz club.

> ***FLETCHER***:
>   Andrew.
>   Hey.
>   [JAZZ MUSIC
>   PLAYING OVER SPEAKERS]
>   I don't know if you heard. Uh...
>   I'm not at Shaffer anymore.
>
> **ANDREW:** 
>   Yeah, I did hear that.
>   Did you quit?
>
> **FLETCHER:** Not exactly.
>   Some parents got a kid
>   from Sean Casey's year, I think,
>   to say some things
>   about me.
>   Although why anybody
>   would have anything
>   other than peaches and cream
>   to say about me is a mystery.

Despite the reassurances that Fletcher would never find out who testified, he has somehow found out and the whole end scene is based around Fletcher getting payback for Andrew causing him to lose his job.